# Alternative to scatterplot plotting in matlab

Tags: matlab, scatter

I am plotting a map between `x`,`y` and `density`. `x` and `y` are distances. Is there any other method apart from `scatterplot` to plot it. I want the density to be shown in colorbar. I have been doing the following:

```
scatter(x(1:end-1), y(1:end-1), 5, g);
colorbar('eastoutside');
caxis([12 max(g)]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `surf(x,y,z)`, in which x, and y are your distances and z is density.